# Although the contiditon is true, the code doesnt enter if statement

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on an android app. I have a string in one of my first activity. And I use `intent.putExtra()` to pass that string to second activity which I started in first activity. Here are the related parts of activity codes:

**First Activity**

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String selectedFromList = (lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());

        Intent content_umre_Intent = new Intent("com.uygulama.hacc.ContentActivity");
        content_umre_Intent.putExtra("key", selectedFromList);
        startActivity(content_umre_Intent);
    }
 });
```

**Second Activity**

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();                      
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("key").toString();

if(text=="abc"){
    toast.show();
}
```

There is something curios here. I put `toast.show()` outside of if statement, and I saw that it is equal to "abc".

However even the variable `text` is exactly equal to "abc" it doesnt go enter the if statement.

Do you have an idea why this happens? I couldnt find any reason. I really need help right now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if(text.equals("abc"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing too curious...change

```
if(text=="abc"){
```

to

```
if("abc".equals(text)){
```

When comparing `Strings`, `==` will compare if they reference the same object. You need `.equals()` to compare if they have the same value.

You can do it as

```
if(text.equals("abc")){
```

but the first way I posted will protect against a `NPE`.

**Off topic**

Why do you have `toString()` on a `String` value?

```
String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("key").toString();
```

Also, if you are inside of the `Activity` and not inside of an inner class or listener then you can use `this` for your `Context` instead of creating a variable. It probably won't hurt anything here but depending on what you are using the `Context` for it could cause problems since you are using `Application Context` instead of `Activity Context`...just be aware.

Comment: I didnt know that. Thank you very much it worked. I was trying to make it worked, I added it without any reason:) I will accept your answer within 5 minutes

Comment: Ok, seems reasonable to me ;) Glad its working

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if(text.equals("abc")){
    toast.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **==** tests for reference equality.
>
> **.equals()** tests for value equality

Its a java string comparison it works with **equals**

```
if(text.equals("abc")){
    toast.show();
}
```

But i would recommend

```
if("abc".equals(text)){
    toast.show();
}
```

because if text is null first will throw Exception but second won't it will be automatically handle with `.equals(object)`

and also you can do this if you don't bother about the case

```
"abc".equalsIgnoreCase(text)
```

Comment: This is true if the `Class` under question has overridden its `equals()` to test for values specific for that `Class`. It is up to the programmer to decide what `equals()` compares. By default `equals()` and `==` are equivalent; they both check for memory reference equality.